# Was there a /t͡ʃ/ to /k/ sound change from Old English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, historical-change, old-english, middle-english

I stumbled upon a strange thing while looking up the etymology of words ending in **"le"**. I looked up "kettle" and saw that it was pronounced with /t͡ʃ/ in Old English and also in Middle English.

An entry from Wikitionary:

> From Middle English *ketel*, also *chetel*, from Old Norse *ketill* and Old English *ċietel*

The pronunciation of [Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cietel#Old_English) **ċietel** is  **/ˈt͡ʃi͜y.tel/** where /t͡ʃ/ can be seen.
In [Middle English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ketel#Middle_English), wikitionary gives three pronunciations: **/ˈkɛtəl/**, **/ˈtʃɛtəl/**, **/ˈtʃitəl/**. One of the pronunciations has /k/, the other two have /tʃ/.

I searched many other words starting with "k" in Modern English, that are from Old English but none of them show the same change. Also, I can't find anything on Google.

Can someone explain why it happened? Was it a one-time change or it applied to other words too?

Comment: *Chest* also has a history of palatalization, and was sometimes spelled *kist(e* in Middle English.

Comment: Churl, cold, chide, seek / beseech...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there wasn't a /t͡ʃ/ to /k/ sound change. It's more likely in cases like this that /k/ represents a form where for some reason, the conditioned /k/ to /t͡ʃ/ sound change that is part of the history of English did not take place.

In native English words, /t͡ʃ/ almost always comes from palatalization of Proto-Germanic *k. (The verb *fetch* is a rare exception where /t͡ʃ/ may be from palatalized *t.) The palatalization of Proto-Germanic *k usually occurred in certain contexts, such as before the palatal glide /j/ or next to a front vowel.

The change of the reconstructed velar stop [k] to the present day palato-alveolar affricate [t͡ʃ] is thought to have proceeded through the intermediate step of a fronted or palatal stop, written [c] in IPA: [k] > [c] > [t͡ʃ]. Some sources argue that in Old English, the palatalized version of *k was still pronounced as the palatal stop [c], and had not yet progressed to the affricate [t͡ʃ].

Palatalization did not occur in Old Norse, so the absence of palatalization in contexts where it would be expected is often a sign that a word was borrowed from Norse. This may be why Wiktionary mentions Old Norse *ketill.*

It may also be possible that different dialects of Old English had different forms of the sound change palatalizing or affricating Proto-Germanic *k – although this is debated, and I'm not sure if there could be any difference in the case of a word like *ċietel.* The specific form *ċietel* belongs to the West Saxon dialect. The Oxford English Dictionary's entry for *kettle* traces the form to a "Mercian and Northumbrian form" *cętel* starting with [k], also acknowledging that some sources attribute the [k] in *kettle* to Scandinavian influence. However, this is an unupdated older entry, and I'm not sure that it reflects modern scholarship. According to  "[Palatalization of Velars:A Major Link of Old English and Old Frisian](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c929/fbdb1d322b568421024734fb63a8fbb0215c.pdf)", by Stephen Laker, all dialects of Old English, including northern dialects such as Mercian and Northumbrian, should have palatalized and assibilated *k before a front vowel (page 181).

Answer (score 4):

**Palatalisation** is the technical term for what caused the change from /k/ to /t͡ʃ/.

You might have noticed that the vowel in the word *keep* (/i/) is produced further forward in the mouth than the vowel in *cool* (/u/). The KEEP vowel is therefore called a ‘front vowel’ and the COOL vowel is called a ‘back vowel’.

The /k/ in *cool* is articulated in the back of the mouth, meaning the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plosive) is made further back in the mouth whereas the /k/ in *keep* is articulated further forward in the mouth in anticipation of the following front vowel—/i/. Because of the following front vowel /i/ in *keep*, the closure for /k/ is made further forward in the mouth (closer to the palate) in order to ease the transition.

In Proto-Germanic (ancestors of English), most of the /t͡ʃ/-words were pronounced with a /k/, for instance, *child, chin, cheese* etc., were pronounced with /k/ (they're still pronounced with /k/ in German). The word *church* was **kirika* in Proto-Germanic  (compare Scot. *kirk*, from Old Norse which retained the original /k/). [Trask Historical Linguistics]

So what happened?

Over time this palatalisation of /k/ before a following front vowel went so far that the /k/ became [tʃ]. That is to say, the closure for the /k/ moved to the front part of the mouth, resulting in an affricate [tʃ]. [Trask Historical Linguistics]

An example of 'palatalisation' in Modern English is the pronunciation of *what you* as *whatcha*: the /t/ in *what* is alveolar while the /j/ in *you* is palatal, the /t/ in this case is articulated near the palatal in anticipation of the following /j/, resulting in an affricate [tʃ].

According to Peter S. Baker (*Introduction to Old English*), Old English *c* (which is sometimes printed with a dot: ***ċ***) was pronounced /t͡ʃ/ before the front vowels *i* and *ie* and the diphthongs *ea* and *eo*.

I don't know what happened to *kettle*, but here's what Donka Minkova has to say:

> The PDE vocabulary shows many such pairs. The presence or absence of palatalisation of an etymological [k] to [tʃ] is responsible for the different initial consonants in ***c**old-**ch**ill, **k**ettle-**ch**ettel* (dial.). Alternative pronunciations in a derivational set or in OE and ON are also behind the [k] ~ [tʃ] alternation in the histories of *ben**ch**-ban**k**, bir**ch**-bir**k**, **ch**est-**k**ist* [...]
>
> [[*A Historical Phonology of English* by Donka Minkova](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Historical_Phonology_of_English.html?id=uGs3BQAAQBAJ)]

Comment: PDE -> Present Day English

Comment: Partial Differential Equation wasn't making much sense in that context - thanks for the gloss.